# How to date format only one column in appsScript getValues() result

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a [table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gOPTmH8S9ir27wlk7BrXZJ3uthgC0xqwqMYiSf_MkqE/edit?usp=sharing) with a `date column`. How do I format only this column with specific date format?

How do I apply this, to the first column only (I care about in memory format only)?

```
Utilities.formatDate(sheet.getRange("G2:G2").getValue(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/YY");


function sendEmail()
{
var bodyStart = mailSheet.getRange("J8:J10").getValues();
var bodyEnd = mailSheet.getRange("J11:J13").getValues();
var values = mailSheet.getRange("Q8:T").getValues().filter(row => row[0] != "");

//Utilities.formatDate(sheet.getRange("G2:G2").getValue(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/YY");

var html = bodyStart.concat(values).concat(bodyEnd).reduce((s, e) => s += "<tr><td>" + e.join("</td><td>") + "</td>", "<table>") + "</table>";

  MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: mailSheet.getRange("B1").getValue(),
  subject: mailSheet.getRange("B4").getValue(),
  htmlBody: html
});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your answer might work but it is not optimal.

It is not a [good practice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) to iteratively use `GAS` methods.

### Solution:

Work instead with the arrays and get rid of the `for` loop:

```
function myFunction(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // change it to your sheet name
  const rng = sh.getRange("A2:A"+sh.getLastRow()); // select the range of your dates
  const newDates = rng.getValues().flat().map(d=>[Utilities.formatDate(d,ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/YY")]);
  rng.setValues(newDates)
}
```

I hope you can adjust the script to your needs. Modify `A2:A` to the column where you have dates. Change `Sheet1` to the name of your sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = mailSheet.getRange("Q8:T").getValues().filter(row => row[0] != "");

for(var i=1; i<values.length; i++)
    {
      var date = new Date(values[i][0]); //convert js date into gs date
      data[i][0] = Utilities.formatDate(date,ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/YY"); //format date using gs method
    }
```